# Avoid "binding param" log on the console Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My process takes basically the double of the time (if not more) because prints a ton of:

```
2021-05-18 15:50:50.588 TRACE 21068 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

However in my `application.properties` I got this:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/#####
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=#####

test.test=idk
redmine.uri = ####
redmine.api-key = #####


spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=#####
spring.mail.password=######
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

So in theory there should not be log about Hibernate or JPA that is binding parameters...

Comment: Remove this line : `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace`

Comment: @SternK i feel a bit dumb...